How to get a record count in SQL
I have been using the following SQL statement to get a count of all the different colors of products the company has sold for a specific week.
SELECT 
  color,
  SUM(case when date BETWEEN '7/7/2024' AND '7/13/2024' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM 
  production_schedule_yearly
GROUP BY color 
ORDER BY color

I was attempting to use this statement within another SELECT statement to get a total of all the products sold that week regardless of color. I have tried several different statements, but none of them seem to be working. Any help figuring this out would be most appreciated.
I have tried a number of different SQL statements, but none of them worked.

Please add both sample input data and the expected result to your question and also tag the RDBMS you use

I'd adjust my previous query to use ROLLUP:
SELECT color,
       SUM(case when date BETWEEN '9/2/2024' AND '9/8/2024' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM production_schedule_yearly
GROUP BY ROLLUP(color) ORDER BY color

ISO SQL:2023, optional feature T431,'Extended grouping capabilities'
If you use MySQL, the ROLLUP syntax is slightly different:
GROUP BY color WITH ROLLUP


That worked perfect. Thank you!

@Tom Martin: if the answer worked perfect, please, accept it.

Are you looking for GROUPING SETS?
    SELECT COALESCE(color, 'All colors')
           SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN date BETWEEN '7/7/2024' AND '7/13/2024' THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
               END)
      FROM production_schedule_yearly
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((), (color))
  ORDER BY color

In the first set - () we set color to null and group all items, second set - (color) uses grouping from your initial query. So the response will be something like this:
All colors 7
Red        4
Blue       2
Green      1


You don't need the sub query to get the results you want
for each product use:
SELECT product, Count(*) as TotalSold
FROM production_schedule_yearly 
WHERE Date  BETWEEN '7/7/2024' AND '7/13/2024'
GROUP BY product

or for all products use:
SELECT Count(*) as TotalSold
FROM production_schedule_yearly 
WHERE Date  BETWEEN '7/7/2024' AND '7/13/2024'


I think you have to specify that it is a subquery.
SELECT SUM(products_sold) AS total_products_sold
FROM (
    SELECT color, SUM(case when date BETWEEN '2024-07-07' AND '2024-07-13' then 1 else 0 end) AS products_sold
    FROM production_schedule_yearly
    GROUP BY color
) AS subquery;


This way did return the total number of products sold for that week, but it did not return the number of products sold for each color. I was hoping to get all of those numbers if one query.
